# Understanding Dynamic Proofs and Objects

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

When I was yet a child, I remember sometimes teachers would commit a geometrical theorem to our intuition using somewhat of a "dynamic" technique in which they would "rotate", "move" and "stretch" geometrical figures. However, I lately came to believe these were only methods of visualization and that such "dynamic proofs" should not be interchanged with rigorous mathematical ones. When I, now, am halfway through my study of Calculus and Introductory Mathematical Analysis began questioning my reckoning on the matter. Throughout the textbook the author included multiple "proofs" using dynamic techniques, for example, to prove the second fundamental theorem of integral calculus (if $f$ is a continuous function over $(a,b)$, then $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiable at every point within $(a,b)$, and $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t) dt = f(x)$) he gives a geoemetric interpretation involving the unrolling of a carpet. But, before that, the author does first provide a traditionally rigorous proof. However, when reading on solids of revolution, I believe they were defined using the dynamic notion of "rotating around an axis". My curiosity rose even higher. I hence must ask: are dynamic proofs and mathematical objects well-understood concepts in the sphere of mathematics? Is it ok to define objects in such ways, and form proofs? I generally just wanted to know more about this phenomenon. That is, about notions such as "revolving", "rotating", "moving". Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is very broad.  As a general matter, arguments such as those you describe can be great for intuition and often do suggest a path toward a rigorous proof, but they are imprecise by nature and often hide critical assumptions.  Hard to say more without greater context.

Comment: Are there any dynamic arguments that should be considered as rigourous as a traditional mathematical proof? Or are all techniques involving such concepts at best used to fortify intuition around the principal?

Comment: Again, far too vague.  Any proof is rigorous if it relies on stated axioms, or on previously proven theorems.  But, as a rule, these arguments are a bit hazy on their axiomatic justifications, hence are not rigorous.

Comment: You might want to read about the controversy attached to Euclid's proof of $SAS$ congruence.  The proof given in the Elements is exactly the sort of thing you are speaking of...the author invokes a previously unmentioned principle of superposition, one which has no basis at all in the axioms.  Very intuitive argument, of course.

Comment: Or worse, Euclid's computation of the volume of a pyramid.  That's an absolutely beautiful argument, one which invokes scaling principles to reduce to an easily solved case, but there is nothing in the axioms to back it up.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer, I shall check on both.